# Nodejs async for random numbers

Tags: node.js

I need to create some random characters of 4-5 length in a nodejs app. 
Here is one module i found.

```
var chars = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
exports.generate = function(length) {
 length = length ? length : 32;
 var string = '';
 for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
  string += chars.substring(randomNumber, randomNumber + 1);
 }
 return string;
}
```

but it seems to be not async. Do i need to worry about it not being async? Is there other way around?

Comment: What do you expect to be async in there? It's just a simple calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have to worry about it not being async (I assume you're worried about your code being blocking?).

A simple benchmark of your code using the default length (32) and 1.000.000 calls runs in about 1.2 seconds on my MBP, so that's pretty fast.

If you want to speed up your code even more, you can try this:

```
var chars = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
...
string += chars[randomNumber];
```

That makes my test run about twice as fast.

Comment: Yes I was worried about it being blocking. So this code is not blocking or is it we can leave it as such because it is simple calculation?

Comment: Well, it *is* blocking, but it's also very fast, so in normal use-cases you have nothing to worry about and you can leave the code as-is.

Comment: thanks, I think i understand it now. But if i had something that took time inside for loop I had to make this code async right?

Comment: Yes, that's true (provided it isn't already asynchronous, like file/network I/O or querying a database).